Clang coverage generates empty default.profraw file
I am doing fuzz testing to a library and using clang coverage to obtain code coverage. This is the command I run:
m smp-fuzzer-cov
LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="/scratch/smp-fuzzer-out/default.profraw" $AOSP/out/host/linux-x86/bin/smp-fuzzer-cov /scratch/smp-fuzzer-out/inputs/*

However, the generated default.profraw files are always empty. In the first command, the -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping flags are used to build smp-fuzzer-cov. I tried several times and letting the fuzzer run 1 hour then stop it, but the file is still empty.
Is it because I manually abort the fuzzer run every time (using ctrl+C), causing default.profraw to be empty? Or is there other reason for this? Thank you.

if you are using separate compiling and linking phases, make sure you add the flag '-fprofile-instr-generate' to the linker as well

Hello Fitsum, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you provide a bit more detail on what -fprofile-instr-generate is and how it might help the user's issue?

I just faced the same problem
and didn't even think about CTRL+C being the problem.
However I've tried exiting the application normally and as it turns out, the file was properly written. So yes, it appears as if you can't use CTRL+C to terminate the program to get the profiling results.

I've partially solved this. I copied 5 inputs from corpus and the fuzzer-cov finished running quickly. So, I think the solution is simply let fuzzer-cov running. If there are too many inputs, what to do is just wait.

But I haven't tested it again with many inputs, it's time consuming. May I know what you mean by 'exiting the application normally'? Thanks.

Exiting without the use of a signal, such as SIGINT (CTRL+C), SIGQUIT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL.
For example by calling exit.
I don't know your specific fuzzer, but using afl-fuzz, specifying the "-V" parameter with a sensible timeout should do the trick.
Otherwise for an ungly hack a remote debugger (like gdb) could be attached and exit called from there.
